# Finding a value within a linked list

Tags: c#, linked-list

I am learning about Linked Lists in C# right now and I'm having some trouble working on them. I've figured out what they are and how to make one, but I have an assignment that I just have no idea where to begin with. Basically, I'm building a static function that receives a linked list (referred to in the function's title as "Node  I") and two numbers ("int start" and "int end") Int start is a place in the list (as in if start=3, it refers to the third place in the list). I need to print out the values in the list between these two numbers.

My problem is, I'm still not sure how I get to the (start) place in the list or the (end) place. In an array I could just write arr[start] but from my understanding you can't do that with a linked list, only to start from the head of the list and go one by one from there. But how do I go from the head of the list to (start) when "start" could be any number?

I would love a hint, or some sample code.

Comment: Please add the definition of the linked list class and the code you have so far to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I recommend that you share any code that you currently have, as this will help others help/understand you.

Given the lack of information of a linked list class, the provided example is done on a linked list of ints which is initialized in the Main method. You can use *while* and the linked list's `First` property to help you iterate through the list. Take a look at the `PrintLinkedList` method and see if it helps you in any way.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var testLinkedList = new LinkedList<int>();
    testLinkedList.AddFirst(1);
    testLinkedList.AddFirst(2);
    testLinkedList.AddFirst(3);
    testLinkedList.AddFirst(4);
    testLinkedList.AddFirst(5);
    testLinkedList.AddFirst(6);
    testLinkedList.AddFirst(7);
    PrintLinkedList(testLinkedList, 3, 6);
}

private static void PrintLinkedList(LinkedList<int> list, int start, int end)
{
    var index = 0;
    while (list.First != null)
    {
        if (index >= start && index <= end)
            Console.WriteLine(list.First.Value);
        
        index++;
        list.RemoveFirst();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. So, I've got no code (I just don't know where to start) and the question doesn't provide any code. It just says the function receives a certain list filled with numbers. Your code actually helped a lot, but let me just make sure I got that right: this list.RemoveFirst()... What does that do? I've never heard of this command. Are you deleting the head of the list with this? How does one iterate through the list without this command?

Comment: Yes, I'm deleting the head of the list with this method. Check out the [LinkedList<T> C# reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=net-5.0) to see the methods that are available to you.